# Determining convergence of divergence with justification: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So I was asked to determine and justify the convergence or divergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)$$ and I think it diverges and was trying to use the Comparison Test by finding a function less than it that diverges but I am not sure what the function would be...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5):

Since for all $n$ suffciently large,
$$\sqrt[n]{n}-1\geq\log(\sqrt[n]{n}-1+1)=\frac{\log n}{n}\geq \frac1n$$
and $\sum\frac1n$ diverges, we know that $\sum(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$ diverges.